# Dozens of apache processes with empty access.logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a strange issue with my VPS: all websites are down, I checked a server and I see about 200 apache processes using ps or top. But access/error logs are not populated with any new lines so looks like no pages are served actually. Could you please advice how to check what happens and what request are processed? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point would be to verify that the web server(s) is up:

> $ netstat -pnlt | grep ':Your-Web-Server-Port-Here'

Then, from a shell (on the server), do:

> $ wget http(s)://localhost/

Also, try to find information in the syslog, /var/log/syslog, and see if you can find anything related to the apache processes:

> $ less /var/log/syslog

Another possible thing, faulty NIC (or software using the network), see if there's a lot of dropped packages (for some reason):

> $ ifconfig (look for the **dropped** row)

Comment: Thanks, mattias. I was able to resolve it with netstat. There were hundreds of connections to apache from the same IP, looks like it is a kind of DOS attack when connections are opened and nothing is requested.